# Why is the cross not a manifold?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds

We consider two lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ crossing at the origin. Intuitively I would say that it is not a manifold (smooth or topological). I wanted to repeat the argument that we can make to argue that the cone is not a manifold (when you remove the origin, is separates an open set around the origin in two disjoints components, this is not true in $\mathbb{R}^2$ so they can not be localy homoeomorphic), but this doesn't work in that case. Intuitively, I understand that by the fact that for the cone the "jump of dimensions" between the rest of the cone and the origin is 2 (we go from a sruface to a point), but for the cross, the jump is only of 1 dimension.

So, how could show this ? I am sure there is a simple trick.

Comment: The same type of argument still applies: if you remove the crossing point from any connected neighborhood containing it, what happens?

Comment: @Kajelad It divides into four connected components when on the other hand we can only obtain two connected components by removing a point of an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$. But is the number of connected components obtained by removing a point a topological property ?

Comment: Yes, the number of connected components can be described entirely in terms of open/closed sets, which are preserved by homeomorphisms.

Comment: Can you point out if the cone is $\{ z^2 = x^2 + y^2\}$ or $\{ z^2 = x^2 + y^2: z\ge 0\}$?

Comment: I meant the first option, but @Kajelad solved the question, for me.